# How to roll a sliding panel on top of Android Activity

Tags: android

I have a sliding panel in my activity. When it rolls out it pushes my activity. But I would like to make it slide on the top of my activity. How can I do that?

```
SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener panelListener = new SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPanelClosed(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-genxxerated method stub
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelOpened(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getActionBar().setTitle("Titles");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then Use a [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) instead of using SlidingPanel